# Sorting based on some threshold in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three lists: right, rightX, rightY
The list contents are:

```
123456 0.7201741337776184 0.028222769498825073
G3/26 0.7428475022315979 0.14198169112205505
BED: 0.6399385929107666 0.14720818400382996
02/12/1979 0.7476143836975098 0.2584814727306366
DOB: 0.6413170695304871 0.26108822226524353
AGE: 0.6393641233444214 0.3781811594963074
32YSEX: 0.7450932264328003 0.379544198513031
M 0.9087993502616882 0.38598716259002686
6056 0.5140257477760315 0.490386426448822
REL: 0.6386545300483704 0.49573469161987305
HINDU 0.7446932792663574 0.4978155195713043
18/01/18 0.7429159879684448 0.6074452996253967
ADM: 0.6375628709793091 0.6129379272460938
PAY: 0.6137194633483887 0.7307364344596863
AUF 0.8062918186187744 0.7317520380020142
PVT 0.726770281791687 0.732855498790741
80611895 0.7259002923965454 0.8441673517227173
FND: 0.6144964098930359 0.847784698009491
```

The first element is text, second element is x coordinate of the text in the image and third coordinate is y coordinate of the text in the image.

I want to sort this list based on some condition :
If the difference between consecutive Y's is less than 0.05 (or some threshold), then the sorting based on X should be done and that text should be appended to the previous one. I want to get text line by line (in order).

The output I am getting is :

```
123456
BED: G3/26
DOB: 02/12/1979
AGE: 32YSEX: M
6056 REL: HINDU
ADM: 18/01/18
PVT PAY: AUF     // wrong output as x coordinate of PAY is lesser than PVT.
FND: 80611895
```

The second last line in the output should be:

```
PAY: PVT AUF
```

The script I am trying is:

```
for text,x,y in zip(right,rightX,rightY):
    if prev_x and prev_y and math.fabs(prev_y - y) <= 0.05:
        lastText = new_right.pop(len(new_right) - 1)
        if prev_x > x:
            new_right.append(text + " " + lastText)
        else:
            new_right.append(lastText + " " + text)
    else:
        new_right.append(text)

    prev_x  = x
    prev_y  = y
    print (text,x,y)

    for text in new_left:
        print(text)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

> EDIT:

A script I have attached to read the above contents into three lists:

```
right = []
rightX = []
rightY = []

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split(' ')
        right.append(line[0])
        rightX.append(line[1])
        rightY.append(line[2])


for text, x, y in zip(right, rightX, rightY):
        print(text, x, y)
```

Comment: The data posted is structured more like a txt file. Can you post the actual contents of the lists?

Comment: I am posting the script which will put the contents into the list after reading from a text file. But in application, they are coming from a list.

Comment: @Ajax1234, I have added the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
a='''123456 0.7201741337776184 0.028222769498825073
G3/26 0.7428475022315979 0.14198169112205505
BED: 0.6399385929107666 0.14720818400382996
02/12/1979 0.7476143836975098 0.2584814727306366
DOB: 0.6413170695304871 0.26108822226524353
AGE: 0.6393641233444214 0.3781811594963074
32YSEX: 0.7450932264328003 0.379544198513031
M 0.9087993502616882 0.38598716259002686
6056 0.5140257477760315 0.490386426448822
REL: 0.6386545300483704 0.49573469161987305
HINDU 0.7446932792663574 0.4978155195713043
18/01/18 0.7429159879684448 0.6074452996253967
ADM: 0.6375628709793091 0.6129379272460938
PAY: 0.6137194633483887 0.7307364344596863
AUF 0.8062918186187744 0.7317520380020142
PVT 0.726770281791687 0.732855498790741
80611895 0.7259002923965454 0.8441673517227173
FND: 0.6144964098930359 0.847784698009491
'''
right,rightX,rightY=zip(*[x.split() for x in a.splitlines()])
rightX=list(map(float,rightX))
rightY=list(map(float,rightY))
prev_x=prev_y=None
new_right=[]
new_left=[]
import math

for text,x,y in zip(right,rightX,rightY):
    if prev_x and prev_y and math.fabs(prev_y - y) <= 0.05:
        lastText = new_right.pop(-1)
        lastText=lastText.split()
        if prev_x > x:
            lastText.insert(-1,text)
        else:
            lastText.append(text)
        new_right.append(' '.join(lastText))
    else:
        new_right.append(text)

    prev_x  = x
    prev_y  = y

for text in new_right:
    print(text)
```